# How do I remove MongoDb fields based on their values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a complex document in MongoDb like below

```
{
  title: "Star Wars",
  episodes: {
    0: {
      episode: 1,
      title: "The Phantom Menace"
    },
    1: {
      episode: 2,
      title: "Attack of the Clones"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I remove episode 1 based on their title? Like I want to remove "The Phantom Menace"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         episodes: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$episodes",
               cond: { $ne: ["$$this.title", "The Phantom Menace"] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KnulrtPYdLM)